# How to change child property when parent property change in a treeview?

Tags: c++, qt, treeview, qml

I want to change the children of a determined parent node in a QML treeview, I thought to iterate through every child and change the property that I want, but I don't know how to get the children list from a parent.
I have the follow QML Menu:

```
TreeView {
  id: tree
  anchors.fill: parent
  model: model
  itemDelegate: CustomNode{
    id: node
    Menu {
        id: menu
        MenuItem {
            text: "Show"
            onTriggered: {
                styleData.value.active = !!+state
            }
        }
    }

    MouseArea{
        anchors.fill: parent
        acceptedButtons: Qt.LeftButton
        onClicked: {
            idNode = styleData.value.vredId
            menu.popup()
        }
    }
  }
}
```

When I click on the node it opens a menu that after clicked in the "Show" button change a property of the selected node, from this node I need to get its children and change the same property that was changed on the parent.

How can I do it?

Comment: It may be easier to implement this on the model side.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`DelegateModel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-delegatemodel.html#details) to obtain the `QModelIndex`es of the children.

```
DelegateModel
{
  id:delegateModel

  rootIndex: styleData.index
}

delegateModel.count // returns the number of children
delegateModel.modelIndex(i) // returns the model index of the ith element.
```

Accessing the data for a given `QModelIndex` is still not that easy, but is already described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22711421/how-to-implement-qml-listmodel-like-get-method-for-an-qabstractlistmodel-derived).

As suggested in my comment, it could be easier to implement this logic on the model side in C++.